# JQuery remote validation - if statement in complete phase

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery validation to double-check entered values. This is working find as long as my controller return true or false. Now I would like to analyze the return value first and then decide if the value is correct or incorrect.

So I am running the remote function like this:

```
supervisor: {
          required:true,

remote: function() {
            return {
                url: "getADobject/" + $('#supervisor').val(),
                data: '',
                complete: function(data) {
                  console.info(data);
                  $(".loading").css('visibility', 'hidden');
                  if(data.responseJSON === false){
                    console.info(data.responseJSON);
                    //$('#supervisor').validate() = false;
                    //return 'false';
                  }
                }
            }
```

The object data returns the correct information and I also can do an if statement. But now I would like to say, yes the validation is OK or not. Can someone tell me how to add this information? I tried it already with an easy return true / 'true' / $valid = true but nothing :(

Thanks in advance

Stephan

Comment: I fail to understand what you're trying to achieve. What does 'but now I would like to say yes, yes the validation is OK or not' mean? Do you want to change the content of an HTML element? Do you want to add a HTML element to your DOM? What is it?

Comment: Let’s say the controller isn’t just returning true or false but instead a JSON. I want now to analyze the json in the if statement and then decide if the entered value is correct or incorrect. Right now, it depends directly on the true or false of the controller.

Comment: I think I could solve it by changing complete to dataFilter. Now I can return true or false like I would like to